# How to display dynamically generated canvas image on other websites

Tags: php, javascript, html, canvas, png

Am working on a site which allows users to participate in polls and earn some points. I'd like them to be able to display their username + score + some other stuff on any website, for example their own blog, forum signatures, etc. as an image. Kindof like stackoverflow flair !

Ofcourse, since their scores and other data will keep changing, I'd like the image to be generated dynamically (I am using php). I have got to a point using canvas where the canvas-png image displays fine on my site, but if I try to use the page url as a src in an img tag, the image doesnot show up.

Below is the page which generates the canvas :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("c"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.fillStyle = "rgb(155, 155, 155)";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 250, 100);
    context.stroke();

    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.onload = function ()
    {            
        // Draw the image on the canvas
        context.drawImage(imgObj, 4, 8, 32, 32);
    }
    imgObj.src="<?=$iUser->avatar?>";

    var username = "Username from php";
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
    context.font = "18px sans-serif";
    context.fillText(username, 42, 20);

    var score = "CGH Score : " + "146";
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
    context.font = "14px sans-serif";
    context.fillText(score, 42, 40);


    var img_data=canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var img_element="<img src=\"" + img_data + "\" />";
    $("#c").remove();
    $("head").html("<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"image/png\"/>");
    $("body").html(img_element);

    //document.body="<img src=\"" + img_data + "\" />";

    //document.write(img_data);
    //var output=img_data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
    //$.post("/show_img/",{image_data:output});


    //window.location = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<canvas id="c"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load that into an image tag, the browser will NOT interpret/execute the JS. it'll try to figure what kind of binary image format (gif/jpg/png/etc...) the raw bytes of that page's source are, and fail. Img tags are not a way to load a remote page/code into a page.

For this to work, you'd need to have the users insert a snippet of JS which loads the script dynamically from your site.

e.g. instead of

```
<img src="http://yoursite.com/canvas.php" />
```

you'd have

```
<script src="http://yoursite.com/canvas.php" /></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create these images with PHP instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Or put this page in an IFRAME if you insist to use Canvas.